# Many To Many relationship in Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, laravel, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony and I'm working on a movie website where you can create movies and link exciting actors to the movies. I already declared the relationship with Doctrine and I have all the movies that are created, but I couldn't find a way to show the actor that is related to the movie. Doctrine already made me a pivot table `movie_actor`

My Movie Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MovieRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\Pure;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MovieRepository::class)]
class Movie
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]

    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]

    private $title;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]

    private $releaseYear;

    #[ORM\Column(type:'string', length:255,  nullable: true)]
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank

     */
    private $description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]

    private $imagePath;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Actor::class, inversedBy: 'movies')]

    private $actors;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(?string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReleaseYear(): ?int
    {
        return $this->releaseYear;
    }

    public function setReleaseYear(?int $releaseYear): self
    {
        $this->releaseYear = $releaseYear;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImagePath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imagePath;
    }

    public function setImagePath(?string $imagePath): self
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Actor>
     */
    public function getActors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->actors;
    }


    public function addActor(Actor $actor): self
    {
        if (!$this->actors->contains($actor)) {
            $this->actors[] = $actor;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeActor(Actor $actor): self
    {
        $this->actors->removeElement($actor);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

My Actor Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ActorRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ActorRepository::class)]
class Actor
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Movie::class, mappedBy: 'actors')]
    private $movies;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->movies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Movie>
     */
    public function getMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->movies;
    }

    public function addMovie(Movie $movie): self
    {
        if (!$this->movies->contains($movie)) {
            $this->movies[] = $movie;
            $movie->addActor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMovie(Movie $movie): self
    {
        if ($this->movies->removeElement($movie)) {
            $movie->removeActor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

MovieController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Actor;
use App\Entity\Movie;
use App\Form\MovieFormType;
use App\Repository\MovieRepository;
use App\Repository\ActorRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class MoviesController extends AbstractController
{
    private $em;
    private $movieRepository;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, MovieRepository $movieRepository,ActorRepository $actorRepository )
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->movieRepository = $movieRepository;
        $this->actorRepository = $actorRepository;
    }

    #[Route('/movies', name: 'movies')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $movies = $this->movieRepository->findAll();
        $actors = $this->actorRepository->findAll();


        return $this->render('movies/index.html.twig', [
            'movies' => $movies,
            'actors'=> $actors
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/movies/create', name: 'create_movie')]
    public function create(Request $request): Response
    {
        $movie = new Movie();
        $form = $this->createForm(MovieFormType::class, $movie);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $newMovie = $form->getData();

            $imagePath = $form->get('imagePath')->getData();
            if($imagePath){
                $newFileName = uniqid() . '.' . $imagePath->guessExtension();
                try{
                    $imagePath->move(
                        $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/uploads',
                        $newFileName
                    );
                } catch(FileException $e){
                    return new Response($e->getMessage());
                }
                $newMovie->setImagePath('/uploads/' . $newFileName);
            }
            $this->em->persist($newMovie);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
        }

        return $this->render('movies/create.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/movies/edit/{id}', name: 'edit_movie')]
    public function edit($id, Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->checkLoggedInUser($id);
        $movie = $this->movieRepository->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(MovieFormType::class, $movie);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $imagePath = $form->get('imagePath')->getData();

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($imagePath) {
                if ($movie->getImagePath() !== null) {
                    if (file_exists(
                        $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . $movie->getImagePath()
                    )) {
                        $this->GetParameter('kernel.project_dir') . $movie->getImagePath();
                    }
                    $newFileName = uniqid() . '.' . $imagePath->guessExtension();

                    try {
                        $imagePath->move(
                            $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/uploads/',
                            $newFileName
                        );
                    } catch (FileException $e) {
                        return new Response($e->getMessage());
                    }

                    $movie->setImagePath('/uploads/' . $newFileName);
                    $this->em->flush();

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
                }
            } else {
                $movie->setTitle($form->get('title')->getData());
                $movie->setReleaseYear($form->get('releaseYear')->getData());
                $movie->setDescription($form->get('description')->getData());

                $this->em->flush();
                return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('movies/edit.html.twig', [
            'movie' => $movie,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/movies/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_movie', methods: ['GET', 'DELETE'])]
    public function delete($id): Response
    {
        $this->checkLoggedInUser($id);
        $movie = $this->movieRepository->find($id);
        $this->em->remove($movie);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
    }

    #[Route('/movies/{id}', name: 'show_movie', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show($id): Response
    {
        $movie = $this->movieRepository->find($id);
        $actor = $this->actorRepository->find($id);
//        $movie = Movie::find(6);
//        dd($movie->actors);
//        $actor = Actor::find(6);
//        $actor->movies()->sync([5]);
//       dd($actor->movies);



        return $this->render('movies/show.html.twig', [
            'movie' => $movie

        ]);
    }

    private function checkLoggedInUser($movieId) {
        if($this->getUser() == null || $this->getUser()->getId() !== $movieId) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('movies');
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This should return a Collection of actors for a movie `$movie->getActors();` is that what you would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `createQueryBuilder`
On your controller, you can add this :

```
$qb = $entity_manager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('movie')
    ->from(Movie::class, 'movie')
    ->leftJoin('movie.actors', 'actors')
    ->addSelect('actors')
;

$movies = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And pass `$movies` on your template.

The `addSelect` method on the query allows doctrine to identify that is a many to many relationship between Actor and Movie.

On your template, you can show the result like this :

```
<ul>
    {% for movie in movies %}
        <li>{{ movie.title }}</li>
        <ol>
            {% for actor in movie.actors %}
                <li>{{ actor.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: A big plus one for using 'movie' instead of 'm' for your movie alias.  For some reason I always get annoyed at the customary approach of reducing aliases to a single letter.  However while you did show an answer I am not sure it's really going to be helpful.  The simple answer ($movie->getActors()) was already given in the comments.

Comment: @Cerad If you care about performance $movie->getActors() is not the best approach because when invoked it creates additionnal query for each actor which is not ideal. The solution above generate only one query to fetch all the information

Comment: @glitchcl your methods works perfect but for now i don't need to use query so instaed i called the movies using the MovieRepostery and i searched the movies that i want by id

Comment: @glitchcl I don't have a test case handy but I'm pretty sure the default many to many implementation will load all the actors in one query when getActors() is called.  However I do generally use custom DQL queries to avoid lazy loading.  Glad your answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using the movieRepostery by adding this code to my public function show where i seached just to show one movie by its $id

```
 $movies = $this->movieRepository->find($id);

        return $this->render('movies/show.html.twig', [
            'movies' => $movies



        ]);
```

and then i used the tow for loops in my show.html.twig the one loop and that is:

```
 {% for actor in movies.actors %}


                    <div class="xl:w-1/3 md:w-1/2 p-4 m-auto">
                        <a href="/actors/{{ actor.id }}">
                            <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
                                <img class="lg:h-60 xl:h-56 md:h-64 sm:h-72 xs:h-72 h-72  rounded w-full object-cover object-center mb-6" src="{{ actor.imagePath }}">
                                <h3 class="tracking-widest text-indigo-500 text-lg font-medium title-font">{{ actor.name }}</h3>
                                <h2 class="text-lg text-gray-900 font-medium title-font mb-4">Description</h2>
                                <p class="leading-relaxed text-base  truncate ...">{{ actor.description }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                {% endfor %}
```

i used one loop because one movie has multiple actors
[image]